# Jasper Reports and huge XML as data source

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a huge `.xml` as data source (about 100 MB). How to prepare a pdf with this xml efficiently and without `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` ?

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
// below i get: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
Document document = JRXmlUtils.parse(JRLoader.getLocationInputStream(dataSource)); 
params.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_XML_DATA_DOCUMENT, document);
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could increase the heap - if possible. But creating a DOM for a 100MB xml file plus creating a pdf document in the same JVM really requires a lot of memory. Try processing the input file with an event based SAX parser. That should decrease the memory footprint significantly!

Comment: Do You know, how to connect XML datasource + SAX parser + Jasper Reports ?

Comment: Actually - no. But maybe you can use a SAX parser based preprocessor to split the huge xml in smaller, parseable documents, just for report creation.

Comment: @marioosh if you look (http://fecplanner.com/jasperreports/docs/faq.html) there is set you can set a system property to set the parser.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using a better XML parser, also check [Jasper Reports - Virtualizer](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/virtualizer/index.html).